# How to type new props in React.cloneElement?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-typescript

I like to pass down a state update function to all children elements like that:

```
React.Children.toArray(children)
.map(child => React.isValidElement(child) ?
React.cloneElement(child, {setNewItemPopup : setNewItemPopup}) : child)
```

TS tells me:

```
No overload matches this call.
  The last overload gave the following error.
    Argument of type '{ setNewItemPopup: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<NewItemPopupProps | null>>; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Partial<unknown> & Attributes'.
      Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'setNewItemPopup' does not exist in type 'Partial<unknown> & Attributes'.ts(2769)
```

I don't know how to do the typing in this case. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since `isValidElement` takes a generic `P` which is a props and returns a valid `ReactElement<P>` so as long as you set the props for it which is the props of element you clone, then it should work.

In short, set as following:

```
// Just replace `any` with your actual type
// while `{ setNewItemPopup: any }` is the props of `child`
React.isValidElement<{ setNewItemPopup: any }>(child);

// so full code looks like this:
React.Children.toArray(children).map((child) =>
    React.isValidElement<{ setNewItemPopup: any }>(child) ? React.cloneElement(child, { setNewItemPopup: setNewItemPopup }) : child
  );
```

Comment: No problem now you can vote @anton